# display cell detail based on a condition

Tags: model-view-controller, view, html-table

I am currently trying to learn MVC functions. This is a form where I am calling the controller method.

I have three columns: Name, DOB, Age

```
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
```

I only retrieve Name and Year from the database.

```
<tr>
<td>@Model.name</td>
<td>@Model.dob</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

I want to display the age based on dob conditions.

if dob = 1990 - 1999
age would be 16 - 25 
if dob = 1980 - 1989 
age would be 26 - 35

How should I go about doing this? I am new at this so please go easy :)

Comment: Hi amy u got the solution for this question

Comment: @vinoth, thank you got it! it was perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can find the age using the following code:

Based on your condition

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <tr>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>@item.dob</td>

         @
          {
               int dyear=@item.dob.year;
               if(dyear>=1990 && dyear<=1999)
                  <td><label>16-25</label></td>
               elseif(dyear>=1980 && dyear<=1989)
                  <td><label>26-35</label></td>
               else
                  <td><label>-----------</label></td>          
           }

       </tr>
    }
```

if u wanna print exact age means use the following code

```
     @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       <tr>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>@item.dob</td>

          @{
             DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            int age = today.Year - @item.dob.Year;      
           }

          <td><label>@age</label></td>

       </tr>
    }
```

Comment: okay but what if its not age. i am just trying to give a rough description of my problem but in other attribute names. it's not actually age.

Comment: Wht you want exactly ? I didnt get you from above comment@Amy

Comment: okay let's say i have 2 or more rows, and I want to display the age based on the dob. how do i get the age for all the dob because all the conditions would be recurring for all those rows. is there a way to create a javascript function and then add it inside the row instead so that the if else condition does not appear at all those specific cell tags.

Comment: Your table row contains name,DOB,age .you want to display all the rows in view ,based on the DOB it should calculate the age and display. this what u need correct